# PHP не обрабатывется исключение

Tags: php, исключения, try-catch

```
    namespace app\commands;

    use DateTime;
    use Yii;
    use yii\base\Exception;
    use yii\console\Controller;

    class TweetsStatisticController extends Controller{

        public function actionIndex(){
            $dateTime ='';
            $stdin = fopen("php://stdin", "r");

            $dateForSearch = fgets($stdin);
            try{
            $dateTime = new DateTime($dateForSearch);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "неверный формат даты!!!";
            }
    }
}
```

Когда в $dateForSearch  присылаю заведомо непарсящаеся значение, выбрасывается исключение.

```
Exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (ываваыв
) at position 0 (�): Unexpected character'
```

Почему блок try/catch не ловит его?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace app\commands;
...
} catch (Exception $e) {
```

Вы пытаетесь поймать `Exception` текущего, а не глобального пространства имён. А исключение генерируется от глобального, т.е. `\Exception`. Они находятся в разных пространствах имён, поэтому это два разных класса.

Comment: А как тогда его можно поймать? Если мне необходимо использовать именно это пространство имен?

Comment: @user199588 автор ответ написал же вариант с обратным слешем

Comment: Действительно))